# multiple apt-get "could not resolve" "failed to fetch" errors

Tags: apt, 20.04, internet, gnome-terminal

I'm a BEGINNER!  I'm a HOME USER trying to move from mac to linux to support privacy and non-proprietary software. I have spent hours researching how to fix this:

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                            
  Could not resolve 'repo.protonvpn.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                           
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                     
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:4 http://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                 
  Could not resolve 'deb.tuxedocomputers.com'
Err:5 https://download.vscodium.com/debs vscodium InRelease                                                                                                                                 
  Could not resolve 'download.vscodium.com'
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease            
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xtradeb/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.tuxedocomputers.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'repo.protonvpn.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.vscodium.com/debs/dists/vscodium/InRelease  Could not resolve 'download.vscodium.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xtradeb/apps/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My new laptop has Ubuntu 20.04LTS.  After some weeks using, I decided to setup Thunderbird (already installed).  *It may be unrelated*, yet immediately post-setup, ProtonVPN would not connect.  After several attempted fixes, I tried to uninstall and reinstall ProtonVPN, and then discovered the problem with apt-get.  (The graphical software installer shows the related "check your internet connection" error.)

My internet connection is working super with my browser.  I do not have a proxy (I had to look up what that term even was) or any such complexity.  I am connected to a phone hotspot and have been downloading files and watching videos successfully for weeks.

No suggested terminal command fixes I've read about have had ANY impact.  I've tried so many I can't begin to remember them all to share, but I have been careful to use low-risk commonly offered suggestions.

My gut tells me this may be related to my changing the port for SMTP outgoing mail in Thunderbird to my e-mail provider's recommendation, but I do not remember the default port number.

I would GREATLY appreciate help, but please talk in "low-level user English."  A lot of the answers provided here are clearly by advanced masters who cannot talk to normal people.  I am intelligent; I've accomplished a lot; I proudly installed cairo-dock, and switched from Nautilus to Nemo for file managing, but I will not understand a LOT of technical terms.

Comment: I have seen several questions on this site about removing protonvpn and hosing your internet connection. Changing a Thunderbird port would not affect apt in any way.

Comment: Were I in your shoes seeking help from the generous community volunteers here, I would not trash them as folks "*who cannot talk to normal people*" and demand that they don't use the proper vocabulary to describe the problem or solution. We were all beginners once. Many of us are home users.

Comment: Thank you, Organic Marble, for a new direction to explore.  I was totally unaware of ProtonVPN possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Problem caused by ProtonVPN kill switch feature.  Steps that resolved:

(Note I had already uninstalled ProtonVPN per their site instructions.)

In terminal, typed:

```
nmcli con show
```

I learned nmcli is a feature that calls NetworkManager (a software utility) from a terminal window.  This utility helps handle network connections.  "Con" stands for connection, and "show" provides a list of the connections on your device.

My results:

```
NAME                      UUID                                  TYPE      DEVIC>
mywifi                    d464cae4-bcd5-4541-b4c9-1e28eb5c03e  wifi      wlo1 >
pvpn-ipv6leak-protection  2979102d-163c-413d-b05c-7d0b579fcad  dummy     ipv6l>
virbr0                    00dc0db5-b704-44f6-be49-f50d18b53ff  bridge    virbr>
anotherwifi               40870db7-e408-45de-aa58-aa5aa81df57  wifi      --   >
Wired connection 1        5df708a6-5dbd-3524-b7a1-3ebaa26123d  ethernet  --   >
lines 1-6/6 (END)
```

Active connections showed a different color, and the "pvpn-ipv6leak-protection" connection appeared active, despite ProtonVPN having been quit on the desktop and moreover uninstalled.

The next step was actually the most time-consuming to figure out.  I had to type

```
quit
```

to exit the nmcli results and once again have a terminal prompt.

I then typed:

```
nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```

which removed ProtonVPN's kill switch connection, and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again worked correctly.

Major gratitude to users Organic Marble (for the point to the solution) and alexbarham (for his answer at [Completely reset all network interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394314/completely-reset-all-network-interfaces)).